# R Markdown LaTeX equations won't render on Windows 10

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I've got an R Markdown document that I can successfully render with knitr on R Studio 1.1.423 and R version 3.4.3 under Linux. It has a bunch of LaTeX equations that render without issue. I use the knit button on R Studio to accomplish this task.

I've got the exact same versions of R Studio/R on Windows 10 and I can't get the LaTeX equations to render at all. Instead of the equation I get `(=)` where the equation ought to be on the rendered HTML webpage. This happens on both the R Studio preview pane, and if I open the generated HTML file in Chrome same issue. Oddly enough the equations do showup in the R Studio source pane when I hover the mouse over them on Windows 10.

[Edit] I've got the latest versions of knitr and rmarkdown installed in R. I've got Tex Live on both Linux and Windows 10. The equation that won't render on Windows is `\( $Yummy = \frac{Effective Mass}{Avacados Constant} \)`.

Comment: MathJax is a JavaScript library for displaying Latex equations in browsers. I'm not sure if lack of MathJax is the cause of your issue, but [here are instructions](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html) for installing it, in case you need to.

Comment: Do you have a version of LaTeX installed?  Pandoc doesn't convert markdown to PDF, it converts to LaTeX source, and the LaTeX processor converts the result to images.

Comment: I've got Tex Live on both the Linux and Windows machines. I remember reading somewhere it's better to have MikTex on Windows machines but that probably doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Why don't you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038) of your code?

Comment: What does `$Yummy` represent? You should rather use `\( \$Yummy ... \)` or `$ \$Yummy ... $`.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up removing the spaces in the equation transforming it from this:

`\( $Yummy = \frac{Effective Mass}{Avacados Constant} \)`

into this:

`\($Yummy = \frac{Effective Mass}{Avacados Constant}\)`

Now it properly renders in Windows 10. Strangely enough both examples render fine on Linux, and I can also get the centered version - *with spaces* - to render properly in Windows 10. It's just the inline version that breaks. This does work:

`\[ $Yummy = \frac{Effective Mass}{Avacados Constant} \]`